# A base change theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, modular-forms

In (Katz's '$p$-adic properties of modular forms and modular schemes', 1972) Theorem 1.7.1., we use the following fact:

> To show $K\otimes H^0(M_n,\omega^{\otimes k})\cong H^0(M_n,\omega^{\otimes k}\otimes K)$, it suffices to show $H^1(M_n,\omega^{\otimes k})=0$. (Assuming $K$ is a $\mathbb{Z}[\frac1{N}]$-module, and $(M_n,\omega)$ is the level $n$ moduli scheme and its canonical differential.)

I am lost in this fact, and I think the main obstruction is that $H^0$ is left exact while $-\otimes K$ is right exact, hence I don't know how to apply methods from resolution or spectral sequence...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Here $K$ is a finite field, right? Try applying the long exact cohomology sequence to the sequence of sheaves $0 \to \omega^k \xrightarrow{[\ell]} \omega^k \to \omega^k \otimes \mathbb{F}_\ell \to 0$.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Unfortunately, the only restriction is that $K$ is a $\mathbb{Z}[\frac1{N}]$-module...